# Extracting content from xpath_node_set generically in pugixml

Tags: xpath, pugixml

Right now I'm performing this xpath query using pugixml:

```
"//a/@href"
```

Using the following code:

```
std::vector<std::string> web::parser::query(std::string xpath)
{
    pugi::xpath_node_set links = document.select_nodes(xpath.c_str());
    std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::string> urls;
    for (auto link : links)
        urls.push_back(link.attribute().value());

    return urls;
}
```

Observe that I need to specify that what I'm querying is an attribute because I call `link.attribute().value())` instead of `link.node().value())`.

Is there a way that I can make this `query` function to work on both cases (attribute and PCData)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consulting the reference manual from pugixml, I saw that `xpath_node` is an union of `xml_node` and `xml_attribute`.

This means that either one of them is null or both are. With that information, I can do this workaround:

```
std::vector<std::string> web::parser::query(std::string xpath)
{
    pugi::xpath_node_set node_set = document.select_nodes(xpath.c_str());

    std::vector<std::string> result;
    for (auto xpath_node : node_set) {
        if (xpath_node.attribute() != nullptr)
            result.push_back(xpath_node.attribute().value());
        else
            result.push_back(xpath_node.node().child_value());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Which appears to be correct in my test cases.